# Regex on positive numeric with dollar sign

Tags: c#, regex

Could someone post some tip on what's the pattern for Regex for postive numeric number with decimal and dollar sign.

Valid:

```
1.50
25
25.50
$1.50
$25
$25.50
```

Comment: Is the `$` actually relevant in correctness or are other currencies considered invalid?

Answer (score 4):

This one should do it:

```
\$?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: and about `()` <- this is capture. i think, that better to use `(?:pattern)`

Comment: +1. My only suggestion would be to change the second `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]{2}`, unless you’re dealing with financial scenarios where precision goes beyond cents.

Comment: I also meant for it to work on values that are greater than 0 or $0, so $0, -5 are not valid.  You patter also accept $0 and negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\$\s*)?([1-9]\d+|\d+)(\.\d+)?
```

This one also excludes $05.00

```
(\$\s*)?(([1-9]\d+|\d+)(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)
```

This one allows $ .3

**Update**: to filter 0 and $0

```
(\$\s*)?(([1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?|0?\.\d*[1-9]\d*)
```